# DTM data type from Int16 to Float

Tags: qgis, dem, earth-explorer

I downloaded a data set 'SRTM Arc-Second Global' from the USGS EarthExplorer (GeoTIFF 1 Arc-second). Apparently, the DTM data type is *Int16* whereas I need *Float*. I am trying to convert the format using the *Raster -> Conversion -> **Translate (Convert Format)** ...* dialogue in QGIS. However, if I run e.g.

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff
-ot Float32
-co COMPRESS=LZW (lossless compression)
 /Downloads/Tra_Vinh_.tif
 /Downloads/Tra_Vinh_float.tif
```

I receive the following error:

> ERROR 6: Too many command options '/Downloads/Tra_Vinh_.tif'

If I use less command options, e.g.

```
-ot Float32
-co COMPRESS=LZW (lossless compression)
/Downloads/Tra_Vinh_.tif
/Downloads/Tra_Vinh_float.tif
```

or

```
-ot Float32
/Downloads/Tra_Vinh_.tif
/Downloads/Tra_Vinh_float.tif
```

It says:

> The process failed to start. Either the invoked program is missing, or
>   you may have insufficient permissions to invoke the program.

Answer (score 2):

qgis uses gdal for raster conversion. if you use the raster > conversion > convert tool in QGIS, you will have a command line that fills automatically at the bottom of the form. Simply use the edit button to add

> -ot Float32

on the command line and run the tool. Note that you can add other usefull option, such as:

```
-co COMPRESS=LZW (lossless compression)

-co TILED=yes (tiling)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Seems like this is going into the right direction. Unfortunately, I cannot find the specific dialogue in my QGIS menu (see edited question above).

Comment: Use *Translate (Convert Format)...*

Comment: Thank you for your support. I am still facing issues. I updated my question accordingly.